# Error codes from API ... What is the good practice to handle

Tags: c++

I am writing a host application using a proprietary API.
This API returns error codes when something wrong happened.
I need your advise(s) about the best way to push up the error codes and manage them in my host application:
Here an short example :

**CCas.cpp**

```
CMD_STATUS CCas::shutdown() const
{
        /* CMD_STATUS_OK is an API return code */
    uint8_t statusByte = CMD_STATUS_OK;

    /* Shutdown the CAS system */
    if (CMD_STATUS_OK != (statusByte = CAS_Master_ShutDown()))
        return statusByte;

    /* Set nReset to HIGH */
    ...
        ...

    /* Done the system is OFF */
    return statusByte;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(char *argc, char **argv)
{
  CMD_STATUS retByte = CMD_STATUS_OK;
  CCas vmx;

  if(retByte != vmx.shutdown())
  /* Something wrong happened */
  return retByte;

  return 0
}
```

In my example, inside the method shutdown when an error is raised I push up to the main the error inside the statusByte variable and inside the main I catch the error and stop the program.

Do I use it in the right way or there is another way to do.
Do I need to create my own error codes in the main.

Please could you advise.

Thanks

Comment: What about launching an exception?

Comment: Your `main` function will return CMD_STATUS_OK if something goes wrong, is that expected?

Comment: This is a pretty typical use case for exceptions, why don't you use them? You should really have a look at this C++ FAQ, especially if you come from the C world: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions - won't take you too long to read but most probably provide huge insight. In your case, since the API uses error codes, I would wrap these in exceptions.

Comment: There's no one true single answer to this question. You could wrap the errors, you could throw exceptions, or just propagate the underlying errors. All three alternatives are equally valid.

Comment: A note about exceptions though: While it might seem tempting to use them, they should be reserved for truly exceptional problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's exactly what makes me always uncertain: What is a _truly exceptional problem_? To make it worse, in an API function is hard to distinguish whether a problem is truly exceptional as the outer context may define this, e.g. a zero vector which shall be normalized. (In that specific case, I ended up with a template parameter to decide whether to `throw` or not.) Things which I consider as truly exceptional problems, I usually handle with an `assert()` (and the hope that we find the most critical things in our S/W tests).

Comment: @Scheff Exceptions is when the standard flow breaks.  Can be anything out of the ordinary.  Div function getting the second operand with a zero value? exception.  User name length too short?  exception.  Don't handle what you don't know - that's probably the most important thing about exceptions, leave it for higher layers to handle.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb To stick to the zero vector (it's my most prominent example): Zero vectors cannot be normalized (mathematically) as this results in division by 0 (practically). An exception! ...if this was an erroneous result of a previous computation. If users are in the loop this should be weakened (IMHO) as I mistrust users in general. To make it worse: exceptions come to a performance price and we are not always willing to pay it.

Comment: @Scheff I can't argue with that, your approach is perfectly valid and I can't say it's wrong, because it isn't. I take a different approach saying exceptions is everything that is out of the ordinary, and I'm willing to pay the performance price for exceptions.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb Actually, you nailed it in your answer _There is no definite answer here, and there is no single approach that is the ultimate golden approach to take._ (Alone this sentence was worth to spent my upvote.) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no definite answer here, and there is no single approach that is the ultimate golden approach to take.
Whatever you do, I would say - keep it consistent.
If you are writing C++ code, you should probably consider using exceptions instead of error codes.
Exceptions help writing your *host* code in a carefree way and help breaking error handling logic from the main code:

```
try {
    apiCall();
    anotherApiCall();
    yetAnotherApiCall();
} catch (someKindOfError){
    // Handle error here
} catch (anotherKindOfError){
    // Handle other errors here
} catch (baseError){
    // A more generic error handling here
} catch (...){
    // Just make sure you don't catch what you can't handle and leave higher layers handle it
}
```

Another approach would be to use error codes, the code is ravaged with `if this` `then that` but it's a valid approach non the less.
In this case, I would form a constant that says success (like the posix 0) and then something like:

```
ErrorType retVal = someApiCall();
if (retVal != ErrorCodeSuccess){
    // either handle generic error or try to find out if it's a specific error, etc.
    if (retVal == ErrorCodeCatIsHungry){
        // Handle error here and probably bail out by calling 'return retVal;'
    }
}
```

Some people use the approach of returning a failed code (`void` functions returning booleans, functions that return objects return `null` or a static flag object to denote an error) and then call a more detailed error function on request: `getLastErrorOfMyLovelyApi()`.
Not my personal taste, but sometimes useful in C APIs where the error can be a complex set of information.
It all comes down to who your audience is, what tools you have for them (C++ has exceptions, C does not), and your personal taste.
If you ask me, exceptions (even just the standard ones from `stdexcept`) is the way to go in your case.